# Getting error while loading data from Netsuite to Exadata throgh informatica

Tags: netsuite, informatica, informatica-powercenter, exadata

While loading data from Netsuite to exadata, I am getting following error for one table as below

FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [NetSuite][ODBC 64 bit driver]Error in row.
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [NetSuite][ODBC 64 bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# iiap9cx01whniqe60ajrc[401]]

The table has around 80,00,000 records. After loading around 5,10,000 records, it is failing to load.

Kindly guide for the same. Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,
Amogh Datar

Comment: Not sure, but, looks like default fetch size for JDBC is 10, do you if there is a way to configure the fetch size in Informatica? if fetch size is optimised it will reduce the number of network round trips drastically. If its configurable try it with 1000]

Comment: In my case I was exporting 1 million record 1/8th of your case, and I used fetchSize of 200, try something between 200-1000. I am assuming there should be a way in Informatica to configure it.